# Conditional not evaluating values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Why is the `Set @subject = "The road is yours"`executed but the if-else conditions are not?

```
%%[

var @subject

set @subject = "The road is yours"

IF City Name == "Hongkong" AND Locale Value == "hk" THEN

 set @subject = "您即將擁有上路接受派案賺錢的大好機"

ELSE

 set @subject = "The road is yours"

 ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: are city name and locale value the name of the variables? you need to put @nameofthefield

Comment: You need brackets around city name and locale value since they have a space

Answer (score 4):

You need square brackets when your names contain spaces. Also, these simple IF statements can easily be rewritten into a single line using little known inline IF function [IIF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm). It returns the second argument if first argument is evaluated to true, otherwise third argument is returned:

```
%%[
VAR @subject
SET @subject = IIF(([City Name] == 'Hongkong' AND [Locale Value] == 'hk'),'您即將擁有上路接受派案賺錢的大好機','The road is yours')
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never been a fan of naked personalization strings.  I'd utilize the [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) and [**Empty**](https://ampscript.guide/empty) functions it like this:

```
%%[

var @subject, @cityName, @localeValue
set @subject = "The road is yours"
set @cityName = AttributeValue("City Name")
set @localeValue = AttributeValue("Locale Value")

if not empty(@cityName) and not empty(@localeValue) then

 set @subject = "您即將擁有上路接受派案賺錢的大好機"

endif

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [**Empty**](https://ampscript.guide/empty)